# How to check if an array is multidimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a code to check if n is the maximum of the array A if it is return True if it isnt return False but I have two conditions if the value is a multidimentional or unidimentional I don't know how to write that:

```
 if [A is unidimentional]:
     maximum=A[0]
     for i in range(A.shape[0]):
         if max(A[i],maximum)==A[i]:
             maximum=A[i]
     if max(n,maximum)!=n:
         return False
     return True

     else:
         maximum=A[0][0]
         for i in range(A.shape[0]):
         for j in range(A.shape[1]):
             if max(A[i][j],maximum)==A[i][j]:
                 maximum=A[i][j]
     if max(n,maximum)!=n:
         return False
     return True
```

if someone knows how I can write that condition it would be very helpful Thanks

Comment: Array is in numpy

Comment: Just look at the values in `.shape()`?

Comment: `A.ndim` is the attribute that tells you the number of dimensions in `A`.

Comment: Thanks it worked :D

Comment: `np.max(A)` does this directly.  Your indentation is messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
d = len(my_array.shape)
print(d)  # Output: 2
```

Now, you can test against `d`, if its value is 2, then your array is 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

```
def is_multidimensional(A):
    return A.ndim > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check whether an array is multidimensional, just check the length of the `shape` of the array

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print len(arr.shape)
```

If that value is greater than 1, then your array is multidimensional

But if all you want to do is check whether `n` is equal to the largest value in the array, you dont need to manually implement that. `np.amax` will tell you that:

```
largest_element = np.amax(arr)

if n == largest_element:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix is multidimensional then max will return a list.

Otherwise it will return an int.

```
if type(max(A))== list:
    # do some stuff for handling multidimensional
else: 
    # do some stuff for handling unidimensional
```

Or you could use numpy in which case

`np.max(A)`

returns an int regardless of A's dimensions.

```
A =[[1,2,3,4],[1,4,5,6]]
max(A)
Out[57]: [1, 4, 5, 6]


np.max(A)
Out[64]: 6
```